# Should we propose a site on Area51 if we know a SE 1.0 site already exists for that topic?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

The title says it all.  If I want to make a proposal, but I know there is a stackexchange 1.0 site out there that covers the same ground, should I make that proposal anyway?

Comment: Wow, you FGIWed me on a __question__.  +1!

Answer (score 4):

It may be **even better** if you approached the current site owner and convinced them to submit the proposal for their own site to be migrated?  :-)

For instance, I've already submitted [a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) for my Stack Exchange 1.0 site, [Basically Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/), to be migrated.  *Need followers!*    :-D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create the proposal.  If it gets through commitment we'll sort out the implications for existing SE 1.0 sites (see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/migration-of-se-1-0-sites/).

Comment: I hate to sound impertinent, but who is we?

Comment: @Matthew Stack Overflow, Inc.  I'm this guy: http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/05/interview-with-lead-developer-david-fullerton/

Answer (score -2):

How can this be avoided when there is no list of SE 1.0 sites available?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: (-1) This should be a comment, also, as mmyers pointed out, the list does exit.

Comment: No, there is an implied answer ie. make the proposal anyway.
Also as far as I can see there is no official list, the one in that question is not complete, nor does it give any indication of the activity of those sites and if they are likely to become 2.0 sites.

Comment: also as you can see by the lack of response to this comment my point would be ignored if it wasn't it's own answer

Comment: Looks like the above link and meta.stackexchange.com are down